# es6 modules 'export = value'

Tags: typescript, request

Please look at the end of this typings file
[@types/request](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/request/index.d.ts)

```
...
declare var request: request.RequestAPI<...>;
export = request;
```

Im trying to import 'request' in my Typescript file

```
import request from 'request';

request(op).pipe(...);
```

I get an error

```
Module has no default export
```

How should I properly import 'request' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried  `import * as request from 'request'` ?

To use the default export syntax, the module would have to have a `export default  request;` instead of `export = request;`

Comment: It should have 'export default', but it has 'export = request'

Comment: Yes, I saw, that is why I suggested you use `import * as request from 'request' ` That works for me and the effect is pretty much the same, you can use `request` as a function.

Comment: `import request = require('request');` would also work.